# PHP MySQL - List all databases except information_schema, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my webpage I want to list all the databases available in mysql through PHP.

The following code lists all the databases:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass123');
$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['Database'] . "\n";
}
?>
```

However, I want to exclude `'information_schema', 'mysql' and 'performance_schema'` from the list of databases.

At mysql terminal, I tried:

```
show schema_name as database from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql');
```

but getting errors....unknown column name schema_name.

Comment: “unknown column name schema_name.” SQL is case sensitive with database,table and column names

Comment: I think that error has more to do with the statement starting `SHOW schema_name` rather than `SELECT schema_name`. That said, `SELECT schema_name as database from etc.` still errors unless you quote the use of the reserved word `database` when using it as an alias. Column names are never case-sensitive in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just exclude from the php side like below.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass123');
$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");

$exclude_db = array('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!in_array($row['Database'], $exclude_db)){
        echo $row['Database'] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Also we can exclude in query itself like below.

```
SELECT `schema_name` from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA  WHERE `schema_name` NOT IN('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');
```